# VBA UI Textboxes background turns black

Tags: vba, user-interface, background, textbox, controls

I have a series of Excel VBA projects with UI's and have never had any problems. We have now migrated to Windows 7 and some users have noted that the textbox control backgrounds are rendering to black on selection of the control (through selection of a radio button).

Today, after rebooting my computer, the same has happened.  This is the code of the radio button event that activates the Text Box.

```
Private Sub optUserInput_Click()

With frmBOMReport.txtPN
    .Enabled = True
    .Locked = False
    .BackColor = &H80000009  'White Background
End With
```

The default is `&H80000005&`.

Has anyone experienced this and if so, what is going on here?

Thanking you in advance for any responses to this.
Carlo

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Use the RGB Function

```
Private Sub optUserInput_Click()        
    With frmBOMReport.txtPN
        .Enabled = True
        .Locked = False
        .BackColor = RGB(255,255,255)  'White Background
    End With
```

`&H80000009` is  a VB `Const` that represents the color of text in caption. So if the text is black your code will black your control's back color.

**Option 2**

Use `&HFFFFFF` const which is the defacto VB `const` for the color white.

Comment: Thanks for your answer JLILI. What I was looking for was if anyone had a similar experience where after years of no issue suddenly things changed for no apparent reason.